# Automatically generate about dialog with versions

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a large application consisting of several dozen micro-service WARs deployed, one of which is a UI controller which supports web clients. I would like to be able to display an 'About' page on the UI which lists the versions of all the component microservices. I can easily generate this list manually by running `mvn dependency:list` with the appropriate filters, but what I would like to do is generate it automatically during the build process, then insert it into the UI service WAR so I can access it at run time.

Comment: If you have microservices the UI should not know which versions of backend services (microservices) are being used nor should that packaged in some way into your UI...What about if you change one of the microservices and deploy a new version than the information is simply wrong...furthermore if you already have found `dependency:list` can also generate that list into a file...

Comment: I guess what I am looking for is a way to invoke `dependency:list` from the pom and capture its output. I know how to package a static file into the service war. And yes, you are correct, if the services get updated after deployment, the version information will be stale, but this is really a debugging tool to get a sense of what's on the system that I am accessing remotely.

Comment: safe the file of `dependency:list` to a target folder `target/...` and package into the resulting war file? which means you need to execute the plugin in the `prepare-package` phase...

Answer (score 0):

The `depends-maven-plugin` will generate a file (by default: `target/classes/META-INF/maven/dependencies.properties`). This file contains a parseable (and passably readable) representation of `dependency:tree` and since it writes this file to `classes/META-INF` it will be available, by default, in your bundled application.

You engage this plugin as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>depends-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-depends-file</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate-depends-file</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And when run you'll see Maven writes this log statement:

```
[INFO] --- depends-maven-plugin:1.4.0:generate-depends-file (generate-depends-file) @ sample ---
[INFO] Created: /dev/code/stackoverflow/target/classes/META-INF/maven/dependencies.properties
```

Here's an example of the resulting file:

```
# Project dependencies generated by the Apache ServiceMix Maven Plugin
# Generated at: Mon Aug 28 18:42:30 IST 2017

groupId = com.stackoverflow
artifactId = sample
version = 1.1-SNAPSHOT
com.stackoverflow/sample/version = 1.1-SNAPSHOT

# dependencies

ch.qos.logback/logback-access/version = 1.2.3
ch.qos.logback/logback-access/type = jar
ch.qos.logback/logback-access/scope = compile

ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/version = 1.2.3
ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/type = jar
ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/scope = compile

... etc
```